# Understanding useState from a jQuery perspective

Tags: jquery, reactjs, use-state

From my understanding, we use useState in React for dynamic values, which in the case of React will be a const instead of a var.

So let's say I want to change the value of a variable upon a button click from false to true and I want to tell the user if a button has been clicked or not. Here's is how I would write it in jQuery:
*page.js*

```
//Define variable 
var buttonClicked = false;
//Define function for button click
$('button').click(function() {
  //redefine variable 
  buttonClicked = true;
  //Show button status
  $('.button').text('Button has been clicked!')
});
```

*page.html*

```
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="button-status">Button has not been clicked</div>
```

How would I write this function in React?

Comment: _"How would I write this function in React?"_... What did you try? StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service

Answer (score 1):

*Page.js*

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Page = () => {
  //create the const for buttonClicked for outputing the value and setClickStatus for the function that will return the value of buttonClicked. 
  const [buttonClicked,setClickStatus] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {/* add the setClickStatus on button click so that when the button is clicked the value of buttonClicked is true. */}
      <button onClick={() => setClickStatus(true)}>Click me</button>
      {/* Display the a message based on the buttonClicked value. 'Button is clicked' for true and 'Button has not been clicked' for false. */}  
      <div className="button-status">{ buttonClicked ? 'Button is clicked' : 'Button has not been clicked' }</div>
    </div>
  );

}

export default Page;
```

Some background: I've done a bunch of React tutorials but the explanations tend to use a lot of jargon so the concepts go out the window as I have to look up what each word means. Whereas in my comments I try to explain what is happening as plainly as possible. Remember we are human beings and we can accept nuance in language and not throw syntax errors.

Comment: the one thing I'm noticing about react is that it's WAY more code than jQuery. jQuery is incredible simple to write and does exactly what you need to do with simple syntax and only a couple of weird things like using `$(this)` in setTimeout . The big advantage React has is that I can add all my HTML, JS, and CSS in one place so it's easier to avoid syntax errors.